# Easiest way to display images in reverse order on jquery-photowall.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently using jquery-photowall.js in one of my projects. 
It works great however it displays the most recent images uploaded at the bottom of the photowall. Can someone recommend a way to show the most recently uploaded images towards the top of the photowall?

The photowall can be [here](https://github.com/creotiv/jquery-photowall).
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a URL to your website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the images appear in reverse order change

1. 

`var photos = {}` to `var photos = []`

2.

```
  photos[id] = {id:id,img:bsrc,width:bw,height:bh,th {src:t1src,width:t1w,height:t1h,zoom_src:t2src,zoom_factor:1.5}};
```

to

```
photos.push( {id:id,img:bsrc,width:bw,height:bh,th:{src:t1src,width:t1w,height:t1h,zoom_src:t2src,zoom_factor:1.5}});
```

3.
 `PhotoWall.load(PhotosArray)` to `PhotoWall.load(PhotosArray.reverse())`

Here's a working [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/opherv/k3B7s/)

Comment: Unfortunately, the photowall does not load after making that change. Any other ideas?

Comment: It would be much easier to assist you if you provide some code or a URL to your site

Comment: My website is using the code found here http://creotiv.github.com/jquery-photowall/example.html

Comment: This doesn't help. I meant the code of your website using the photowall library.